# Many to Many, 1 to Many, Many to 1 Relation in Custom fields

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, custom-field, public-group

**Use case** : It is for project management, where manager can enter modules and assign to some developers to test this functionalities. Manager can assign `many modules to one developer(user) or one module to many users likewise.`

This is almost similar to Account Team for an Account.

Here my object name is Module__c

Fields are,

```
       Enter_Modules__c(multi-line text box)

       Assign_To__c(multi-line text box in order to choose many users)
```

see below image usecase
[image]

Later I want to query these assigned users to send Email.

**I just want to know how this can be achievable in custom object.**

Comment: 1) Create junction object called TypeModuleDeveloper or whatever
2) Use custom visualforce for editing of Type module or User by fetching all Users(modules) and displaying in multipicklist, and on save -- removing or adding corresponding junction records - https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000091mrIAA

Answer (score 1):

The `AccountTeamMember` relationship you mention is modelled using a [junction object](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_manytomany.htm):

[image: Sharing and Team Selling Objects]

(image from [Sharing and Team Selling Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_sharing.htm)).

Your job in Visualforce is to list the candidates for the two mult-select picklists and then create the corresponding junction objects on the save. That is probably most easily done using this [Multiselect Picklist Visualforce Component](https://github.com/metadaddy-sfdc/Visualforce-Multiselect-Picklist).

If you support editing, remember that you may also have to delete some junction objects to remove relationships that have been de-selected.

**PS**

In response to the comment, you would create two multi-select picklists (here is what one of them might look like; assume the other populates `users`) using either:

```
<apex:selectList value="{!modules}" multiselect="true">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!moduleOptions}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

and in the controller:

```
public Id[] modules {get; set;}
public SelectOption[] getModuleOptions() {
    SelectOption[] options = new SelectOption[] {};
    for (Module__c m : [select Id, Name from Module__c]) {
        options.add(new SelectOption(m.Id, m.Name));
    }
    return options;
}
```

or the component linked to earlier.

Then on the save you use the selected ID values in `modules` and `users` to create instances of your junction object.

Comment: So, what I understood is  I have to create another object with fields to type "module name" in a multi line textbox and "Assign users" by using custom  multi-picklist. Now on the Module__c object i have to create master-detail relationship to that object. right?

Comment: @sfdc I added a PS to the answer.